# Formation of 5 letter word from 10 distinct letters

Tags: combinatorics

Ten different letters of alphabet are given, words with 5 letters are formed from these given letters. Then, the number of words which have at least one letter repeated is:

Please dont duplicate this question although it is a duplicate one. Because my student wanted me to solve this question with cases rather than by inclusion exclusion principle(10!-10P5)

My approach
Case 1) All 5 same

$\binom{10}{1}*\frac{5!}{5!}$

Case 2) 4 same and 1 different

$\binom{10}{1}*\binom{9}{1}\frac{5!}{4!}$

Case 3) 3 same and 2 different

$\binom{10}{1}*\binom{9}{2}\frac{5!}{3!}$

Case 4) 3 same and 2 same

$\binom{10}{1}*\binom{9}{1}\frac{5!}{3!*2!}$

Case 5) 2 same, 2 same and 1 different

$\binom{10}{1}*\binom{9}{1}* \binom{8}{1}*\frac{5!}{2!*2!}$

Case 6) 2 same, 3 different

$\binom{10}{1}*\binom{9}{3}*\frac{5!}{2!}$

Not getting the answer 69760

Comment: "my student wanted me to solve this question with cases rather than by inclusion exclusion principle" Why?  That's so much more cumbersome.

Comment: Actually this is a good  question, although they got the answer they wanted to know the nuance of solving this question which will give insight of solving other type of question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is in case 5. You’re counting the word $AABBC$ twice, once where $A$ is the first letter chosen, and once where $B$ is. Divide that case by $2$ again, and you should have it.

Comment: @G Tony Jacobs can i use $\binom{10}{2}*\binom{8}{1}*\frac{5!}{2!*2!}$ for Case 5

Comment: That should work.... do you get the right number now?

Comment: Yes i got the answer, thanks a lot